# How to get youTube channel featured-video URL using youTube API?

Tags: ios, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to get a Youtube channel featured or default video ID from youtube API.How can I get the youTube featured-video URL using the youTube API?

Comment: This issue was reported last 2012 but [the thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/youtube-api-gdata/z0x1vmjTsP4) was discontinued. Try opening a new [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new).

Answer (score 0):

You can use videoCategories and guideCategories for that.

[Here's the full blog.](http://apiblog.youtube.com/2013/09/what-to-watch-our-apis-can-help.html)

[GDL video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LcrG0_XTO9o).